# Camera orientation goes back to default after previous activity's onStop was called

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I have a question for my android application.
In my main activity, said activity B, I setup camera orientation to be the same as the display, at onResume().
Before it goes to activity B, i have another activity (said activity A), and it looks like the camera orientation goes back to the default one it call activity A's onStop()

Here is the flow:

```
Activity A onCreate()
Activity A onResume()
Activity A onPause()
Activity B onCreate()
Activity B onResume()
  set mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
----> set properly, i can see the good orientation about 1-2 ms.
Activity A onStop()
----> camera orientation goes to default.
----> If i didn't do anything here, device will sleep, once i wake up, i can get the camera orientation i want
Activity B onPause() --> due to device sleep
Activity B onResume() ---> because I turn on back device
  set mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
---> camera orientation is good now
```

My question is 
"How to setup so the previous activity's onStop() will not change the orientation back to default?"

I added android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" at manifest file for my activity B, but it's not working

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Persist a boolean in [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in Activity B after the orientation is set. False can mean one orientation and true can mean another. Then you can check the boolean in onResume of Activity B. This way will let you persist the the orientation between the activities in the app or data getting cleaned out of memory.

Note: You can save the any primitive data and Strings in sharedPreferences. I just chose boolean because you only needed to save 2 states.

Comment: My orientation is setup at onResume() of Activity B itself. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges, it states 
Unless you specify otherwise, a configuration change (such as a change in screen orientation, language, input devices, etc) will cause your current activity to be destroyed, going through the normal activity lifecycle process of onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() as appropriate.

In this case the camera orientation went to default once the previous activity's onStop() was called.

Comment: @user1193079 Yes, I know. What is happening is your result variable which you use to set the orientation is being cleared out of memory (or possibly being set to the wrong value after Activity A's onStop is called), so it reverts to the default value and the default orientation. You must use persistent storage to save the orientation if you want the value to persist between activities. In onResume() you need to check the persistent storage (which I recommend sharedPreferences for) and reset the orientation based on that value.

Comment: I found the real root cause of this issue,This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos. I found the real root cause of this problem.